# While resolving: react-data-table-component@7.0.0-alpha-5 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Im getting below error while installing npm packages for react.

[image: Image1]

My package json file

[image: Image2]

i tried running below command to overcome the issue but still got npm packages error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no "below command", or maybe something else is messed up. Also, don't post pictures of code, commands, output, configuration files etc.

Comment: If the command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` not helps, you also could try to run `npm install --force`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error might be with the internal dependencies. Do try removing node modules completely and installing it again. Also if it doesn't work, can you try this command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. It might help solve the issue.

Comment: tq for your help.  still some issue im getting, i will update here once this fixed.

Comment: Its resolved after adding similar version of nodejs 16. Thank you for assistance.